# apply style to a div in just 1 page

Tags: html, css

I have the below style:

```
.field.field--name-name.field--type-string.field--label-hidden.field__item.quickedit-field {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 200px;
    background: #a02853;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
```

I want to apply this to div in /blog/* pages alone. How to do this?

The div I'm trying to apply this to:

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="taxonomy_term/2695/name/en/default" class="field field--name-name field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item quickedit-field">Term1</div>
```

Comment: give a parent div an id and add an id identifier at the beginning OR a unique class

Comment: ok 1 sec, i'll update my question with the existing one.

Comment: can you edit the html?

Comment: No, it's coming from a template that i cannot edit. :(

Comment: is that the parent most div? is the position always the same?

Comment: what files can you control/edit? can you give a broad/general overview of file structure?

Comment: Without much context its hard to give a solution.

Comment: @Jiah If you are using framework, this can be easily achieved using url/request related helper/method/function. I doubt you can not change style according to URL without the help of JS or anything similiar

Answer (score 0):

we have several solutions for this question. first of all you have to set unique class into **body** tag and call the body class before **.field.field--name-name.field--type-string.field--label-hidden.field__item.quickedit-field**

Secondly, you have to use a specific **id** for element and you use it in **style** but I don't recommend using it.